# Disqus seems to be taking longer than usual on iOS UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, disqus

We have a website where we use Disqus for commenting. The plugin works perfectly well on all browsers, even on iOS's Safari but fails to load on iOS UIWebView inside the app. Disqus keeps loading and says that Disqus seems to be taking longer than usual - and it never loads. Any ideas of what might be causing this and if it's a problem with my UIWebView? Thanks

Comment: Is the UIWebView pointing to an internal page within the app, or an externally-hosted page? It would matter because the embed won't load unless it's coming from a valid referrer

Comment: it's linking to an externally-hosted page? the embed works on every browser - i would believe uiwebview would act in a similar way. is there a way to make it act as such if not? Thanks

Comment: I tried setting the referer and allow cookies on the uiwebview but no luck so far

Comment: I believe you might need to set the host as well, but regardless I'll post the answer and just let me know if this fixed the issue or not.

Answer (score 1):

Using Disqus on locally hosted HTML files has been possible before, but is definitely not supported so I'd recommend against trying to make that work. Instead you can host the embed on a static CDN using a template like this one: https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes/blob/master/mobile/js/mobiletemplate.html

Then you can pass in the parameters for that discussion (disqus_url, disqus_identifier, etc.) via querystring.

Keep in mind that when you host the embed through an web view you have to account for the following:

**Logging in**

The login buttons expect to be loaded in a popup, so you have to listen when the UIWebView starts navigating to those login URLs and handle navigating back to the comments when they're successfully logged in. You can find an example of the patterns to look for here: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472096

**External links**

Additionally, there will be some links to external pages in the embed, either through comments or the discovery box. You'll have to listen for those and open Safari to avoid having users navigate away from the comments.